# User Defined Data Types with COLLATION

Tags: sql-server, collation, user-defined-types

I am trying to find a way of specifying a `COLLATION` for a user-defined data type, but it doesn't appear to support collations in SQL Server, and it basically takes the collation from the database.

Is there any way of applying a collation against a user defined data type that doesn't inherit from the database collation?

I am writing a database comparison tool, using the `AdventureWorks2012` database for testing, and after generate an SQL diff script and running it on a blank database the tool is now reporting a lot of differences due to the collation being different to what was actually expected.

I could create the blank database with the same collation as the source database, but I need to consider situations where organisations, etc. may wish to change the collation on the database and my tool will not work consistently and will keep on reporting differences.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot specify a different collation for a UDT so the default database collation is always used.  If you want to ignore collation differences, your tool will need to be smart enough to do so.  This applies to meta-data in general, not just UDTs.

Comment: That's what I was worried about.  I will have to consider adding some functionality to ignore collation differences to avoid the tool from reporting on these differences.